# Django admin page redirecting to the same login page even after providing correct credentails

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on a django project where i cant access the admin page when deployed to Digitalocean droplet with nginx/gunicorn , it is redirecting to the same login page again and again
However when i run the server using  python manage.py runserver on port 80 , it works fine

Comment: then share your ngnix/gunicorn configs

Comment: look at nginx/gunicorn config and also might be "if DEBUG=true" statement in urls.py ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?